# What song plays in episode 59 at 17:00 in Fullmetal Alchemist Brotherhood?

Tags: music, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

There's a song playing in episode 59 *Lost Light* at 17:00 in *Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood*. It's different from *Sorrowful Stone* and *Lapis Philosophorum* and I can't find it.

What song is it?

Answer (score 1):

The song you're looking for is this one: **Violoncello's Lament**

It is part of OST 3 and can be heard on YouTube at this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3ORA6x-Wk8&ab_channel=wd0